# SQL query to select all teachers not in different table

Tags: sql

For homework I had to do the following:

> Give a list of all the teachers that don't have a classroom assigned to them.

It involves the following 2 tables:

[image: SQL Table Teachers]

[image: SQL Table Groups]

`Code` inside Groups table would be the classroom in this case and `TeacherId` matches the `Id` inside Teachers table.

My solution to the problem is the following query:

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName
FROM Teachers
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT TeacherId FROM Groups)
```

It works perfectly, however, I wonder if there was a better solution using `JOIN`s.

Edit:

I should mention there is a `CONSTRAINT` on the Groups table:

```
ALTER TABLE Groups
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Groups_Teachers]
FOREIGN KEY (TeacherId)
REFERENCES [Teachers] ([Id])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query using `NOT IN` is good, but you can also use `LEFT JOIN` and keep only the teachers who don't have Groups:

```
SELECT t.Id, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName
FROM Teachers t LEFT JOIN Groups g ON t.Id=g.TeacherId
WHERE g.TeacherId IS NULL
```

Comment: Sorry I had a local cache issue to resolve in order to test your code. It's working perfectly! Thanks a lot :)